# Convert date string to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've this string: "2016-10-08 00:20:00.000000". And I need it as an NSDate  (Date for swift 3) object.

I've tried with the following:

```
let formatterJsonDate = DateFormatter()
formatterJsonDate.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

print(formatterJsonDate.date(from: "2016-10-08 00:20:00.000000"))
```

I always return nil value. What's wrong? I guess it's something about the date format.

Comment: `yyy` should be `yyyy` .. one `y` is missing

Comment: right. I still get a nil value

Comment: Write the dateFormat above the date string. Check if each "value" has it translation in the format. You'll see the missing year character, and the stuff after the seconds...

Comment: @JoseMartinFit http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/
very helpfull tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format and your time string should be same. In your case it should be like,

```
 let formatterJsonDate = DateFormatter()
 formatterJsonDate.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

 print(formatterJsonDate.date(from: "2016-10-08 00:20:00"))
```

Or change dateformatter like,

```
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
```

And `hh` should be capital for 24 - hour format!!!! like `HH`!

Answer (score 0):

If you want use nano seconds your code must be :

```
let formatterJsonDate = DateFormatter()
formatterJsonDate.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSS"
if let myDate = formatterJsonDate.date(from: "2016-10-08 00:20:00.000000")  {
    print(myDate)
} else {
    print ("Invalid Date")
}
```